# MYSQL JSON_CONTAINS and MEMBER OF return weird results when index on json array column is present

Tags: mysql, json, indexing

```
SELECT VERSION();
# => 8.0.28
```

Lets create dummy table with json column and fill the table with 10 000 of rows with random arrays of 10 values:

```
create table dummy_table2 (id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, json_column JSON);

INSERT INTO dummy_table2 (json_column)
WITH RECURSIVE seq AS (SELECT 0 AS value UNION ALL SELECT value + 1 FROM seq LIMIT 100)
SELECT JSON_ARRAY(
                   CAST((FLOOR(RAND() * (100 - 1)) + 1) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER),
                   CAST((FLOOR(RAND() * (100 - 1)) + 1) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER),
                   CAST((FLOOR(RAND() * (100 - 1)) + 1) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER),
                   CAST((FLOOR(RAND() * (100 - 1)) + 1) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER),
                   CAST((FLOOR(RAND() * (100 - 1)) + 1) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER),
                   CAST((FLOOR(RAND() * (100 - 1)) + 1) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER),
                   CAST((FLOOR(RAND() * (100 - 1)) + 1) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER),
                   CAST((FLOOR(RAND() * (100 - 1)) + 1) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER),
                   CAST((FLOOR(RAND() * (100 - 1)) + 1) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER),
                   CAST((FLOOR(RAND() * (100 - 1)) + 1) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)
           )
FROM seq as seq1 JOIN seq as seq2 ON 1 = 1;
```

Check the count of rows including some arbitrary number:

```
select count(*) from dummy_table2 where JSON_CONTAINS(json_column, CAST(51 AS JSON), '$')
# => 969
select count(*) from dummy_table2 where JSON_CONTAINS(json_column, CAST(51 AS JSON), '$') = 1;
# 969

select count(*) from dummy_table2 where CAST(51 AS JSON) MEMBER OF(json_column)
# => 969
select count(*) from dummy_table2 where CAST(51 AS JSON) MEMBER OF(json_column) = 1
# 969
```

now let's create index on json column and check the results:

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 on dummy_table2((CAST(json_column as UNSIGNED ARRAY)));
```

Both MEMBER OF variations return 969:

```
select count(*) from dummy_table2 where CAST(51 AS JSON) MEMBER OF(json_column)
# => 969

select count(*) from dummy_table2 where CAST(51 AS JSON) MEMBER OF(json_column) = 1
# => 969
```

but for some reason both of them does not use index, but table scan

```
-> Aggregate: count(0)  (cost=2019.45 rows=9976) (actual time=17.437..17.437 rows=1 loops=1)
    -> Filter: (<cache>(cast(51 as json)) member of (dummy_table2.json_column) = 1)  (cost=1021.85 rows=9976) (actual time=0.139..17.253 rows=969 loops=1)
        -> Table scan on dummy_table2  (cost=1021.85 rows=9976) (actual time=0.037..7.882 rows=10000 loops=1)
```

JSON_CONTAINS is even more weird:

```
select count(*) from dummy_table2 where JSON_CONTAINS(json_column, CAST(51 AS JSON), '$') = 1;
# => 969
```

and again table scan

```
-> Aggregate: count(0)  (cost=2019.45 rows=9976) (actual time=101.233..101.234 rows=1 loops=1)
    -> Filter: (json_contains(cast(json_column as unsigned array),json'[51]','$') = 1)  (cost=1021.85 rows=9976) (actual time=0.248..101.074 rows=969 loops=1)
        -> Table scan on dummy_table2  (cost=1021.85 rows=9976) (actual time=0.036..71.168 rows=10000 loops=1)
```

But take a look at this count

```
select count(*) from dummy_table2 where JSON_CONTAINS(json_column, CAST(51 AS JSON), '$') 
# => 130
```

BUT it uses index!

```
-> Aggregate: count(0)  (cost=71.76 rows=130) (actual time=1.473..1.473 rows=1 loops=1)
    -> Filter: json_contains(cast(json_column as unsigned array),json'[51]','$')  (cost=58.76 rows=130) (actual time=0.067..1.454 rows=130 loops=1)
        -> Index range scan on dummy_table2 using idx1 over (51 MEMBER OF (json_column))  (cost=58.76 rows=130) (actual time=0.060..1.153 rows=130 loops=1)
```

So can anyone explain me what is going on?

1. Why index is not used in most examples and how to force myysql to use it
2. Why still all of the queries are fast (less than 50ms) on 10k of rows
3. Is there a difference to compare the result of `JSON_CONTAINS/MEMBER OF` with `true/false` and not 1 or 0? I thought there should not be the difference since 0 is false for MSQL and 1 is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug, see [Multi-Valued Indexes only takes into account a portion of a whole data](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=106580).

You can see that when using your index, the execution plan only says "rows=130".

It is fixed in [MySQL 8.0.30](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-30.html):

> InnoDB: A query on a table with a JSON column returned only a partial result set after adding a multi-valued index. (Bug #106621, Bug #33917625)